# Improving performance of levenshtein distance in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have the following function:

```
def levenshtein(seq1, seq2):
    size_x = len(seq1) + 1
    size_y = len(seq2) + 1
    matrix = np.zeros ((size_x, size_y))
    matrix[: , 0] = np.arange(size_x)
    matrix[0, :] = np.arange(size_y)

    for x in range(1, size_x):
        for y in range(1, size_y):
            if seq1[x-1] == seq2[y-1]:
                matrix [x,y] = min(
                    matrix[x-1, y] + 1,
                    matrix[x-1, y-1],
                    matrix[x, y-1] + 1
                )
            else:
                matrix [x,y] = min(
                    matrix[x-1,y] + 1,
                    matrix[x-1,y-1] + 1,
                    matrix[x,y-1] + 1
                )
    return (matrix[size_x - 1, size_y - 1])
```

And I want to apply it to many pairs of string, in order to do it as fast as possible I want to remove the for loops in it and replace them by some vectorization, but I couldn't find a good way to do it, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use [already written python mudule](https://rawgit.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/master/docs/Levenshtein.html) to solve your problem rather than reinventing the wheel, as for me. You will save a lot of time.

Open `cmd` and write `pip install python-Levenshtein`, or if you use git go to your project folder and type `git clone https://github.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein.git` ([github link](https://github.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein#documentation)). Then onen python file and:

```
import Levenshtein
Levenshtein.distance('Levenshtein', 'Lenvinsten')
# output will be 4
# ... your code ...
```

But if you need to write it manually you can see how it is written by other developers or  [examples of using Levenshtein module](https://rawgit.com/ztane/python-Levenshtein/master/docs/Levenshtein.html#Levenshtein-distance) in the same link.

Comment: @BrunoMello no problem, just surf github\pypi :)